# React Navigation with nested stack and drawer navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Am trying to develop an simple app, which has auth , drawer , and other stacks ! I am unable to nest each of these.

This is the flow :

```
 --AuthStack
   --SplashScreen
   --Login
   --FogotPassword
   --DrawerStack
 --DrawerStack
   --MainAppStack
   --Training
   --etc
 --MainAppStack
   --Home
   --screen2
   --screen3
```

etc, For example After auth flow, my main screen would be drawer screen which is Home Screen from mainAppStack. Now, how can i navigate from home to screen2 and screen3 etc ?

I am not getting header, and i couldnt set header title. And while using hardware back its going to Home screen.

Please Guide !

And my navigator setup !

```
   const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Home: {
screen: Home,
navigationOptions: {
 header: null
 }
},
StoreList: {
screen: StoreList,
navigationOptions: {
  header: null
 }
},
EditSurvey: {
screen: EditSurvey,
navigationOptions: {
  header: null
 }
},
StoreSurvey: {
screen: StoreSurvey,
navigationOptions: {
  header: null
 }
},
Competition: {
screen: Competition,
navigationOptions: {
  header: null
 },
},
Display: {
screen: Display,
navigationOptions: {
  header: null
 },
}, 
SurveyCheckList: {
screen: SurveyCheckList,
navigationOptions: {
  headerTransparent: true
 }
},
});

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
Dashboard: {
  screen: AppStackNavigator,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Home",
  }
},
Training: {
  screen: TrainingList,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Training"
  }
},
RoutePlan: {
  screen: RouteCalendar,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Route Plan"
  }
 }
},
{
 contentOptions: {
  activeTintColor: '#127CC1',
 },
 contentComponent: props => <DrawerComponent {...props}/>,
 drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
 drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
 drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
 navigationOptions : ({navigation}) => {
  const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  const headerTitle = routeName;
  return {
      headerTitle,
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon name="md-menu" style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} 
        onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
      )
    }
  }
  }
 );

 const AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
 {
 SplashScreen: {
 screen: SplashScreen,
 navigationOptions: {
  headerTransparent: true
  }
 },
 LoginScreen: {
 screen: Login,
 navigationOptions: {
  headerTransparent: true
 }
 },
 Drawer: DrawerNavigator,
 });
```

Comment: Can you show us how you set up your navigators?

Comment: I have added the code setup kindly check please @zaytrix

Comment: You aren't getting any headers because you're setting `header: null` in the `navigationOptions` of every screen in `AppStackNavigator`. What issue exactly are you having with navigating? `this.props.navigation.navigate(yourRouteName)` should work.

Comment: I have added `header:null` because, when its not null it shows dual header. So only i added null, And the problem i am facing is. The drawer has three routes, and once we navigate to that route for example - RoutePlan ( upto this everything is good ) So once i want to navigate to some other page like StoreList (from AppStackNavigator ) from RoutePlan the header title changes to Dashboard (which is initial route of Drawer) and even i couldnt see back buttons to navigate back and also when i hardware back , it resets to Dashboard screen. This is the problem i am facing

Comment: The expectation is , like the drawer will be used to navigate only for those three routes, and once navigated and from there is there is any other navigation done it shouldnt be under drawer, it should have different title and also back button on top leftt ( which will come by default on stackNavigator )

Comment: Any updates ?@zaytrix

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following your explanation, however if you could reproduce this issue in a snack https://snack.expo.io/ that would help me pinpoint the issues